# Blank program does not exit on linking in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mingw

I've been trying to compile `ndn-cxx` on Windows, and get the following very strange behavior with both MSVC and mingw64 (everything works fine on Linux and Mac).

After the program returns from `main()`, the console gets stuck. Under mingw64 bash, a Ctrl+C closes the program, but this doesn't work in Powershell. Even more interestingly, when I try to view the threads of the program in Sysinternals Process Explorer, then the program shuts down gracefully as expected.

Even a blank `main.cpp` linked against other files exhibits the same behavior. A plain hello world works as expected.

EDIT: The project uses boost (in particular, asio might be related to this?), openssl and sqlite as the only libraries

Comment: if exist concrete *exe* easy possible look for it and say what and why.

Comment: @RbMm what? ...

Comment: if you upload exe which *does not exit* - easy possibly run it and say why this. without binary code, based only on your info - not sure that possible say why

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is due to a deadlock produced by `boost::log::sinks::asynchronous_sink`, probably a bug in either Boost or Windows. Switching to `synchronous_sink` fixes the issue.